# Pragmatic and widely agreed settings for jshint

Tags: jslint, jshint

We're just starting to use JSHint / JSLint and are looking for some "best practice" type settings that are widely considered to be a good compromise between strictness and pragmatism. I've had a look on the internet and not really been able to find anything.

I realise it's all down to personal opinion but I would have thought that some sort of consensus would have formed by now. For example does anybody know what jquery, google, yahoo etc code to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It definitely is a matter of personal style, but you can see many examples from open source projects:

- [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/.jshintrc) or [jQuery UI](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/.jshintrc)
- [Mozilla browserid](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid/blob/dev/.jshintrc)
- [yeti](https://github.com/yui/yeti/blob/master/package.json) (from Yahoo yui)

So if you pragmatically combine them you get something like that:

```
{
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "eqnull": true,
    "expr": true,
    "latedef": true,
    "onevar": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "node": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true
}
```

Comment: @Stan "onevar" has been removed, as jshint headed in another direction. For style checks ESlint seems to current way to go, and [it comes with a "one-var" option](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var).